# Filename search in MS Forms app whereby filename will contain 6 random integrs in a row

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating an app that searches directories for files of certain types and returns list. Works fine. Need to add function in vb.net that will search for (6) wildcard numbers in a row LIKE "160107" somewhere in filename. Cannot find a suitable mask or code that will work. I've googled myself to death.Need help

Comment: You might want to show the basic code you are using and maybe some of the things you've tried.  This will give anyone interested in answers a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regular Expressions, this example will find filenames with **exactly** six digits in them:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fbd As New FolderBrowserDialog
        If fbd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

            Dim RegexPattern As String = "(?<![0-9])[0-9]{6}(?![0-9])" ' exactly six digits
            For Each FullPathFileName As String In Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath)
                Dim FileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FullPathFileName) ' exclude the path portion, just search the filename itself
                Dim matches As RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(FileName, RegexPattern)
                For Each match As RegularExpressions.Match In matches
                    Debug.Print(match.Value & " in " & FullPathFileName)
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

This will allow **more than one six digit occurrence**, however, such as "Test123456Test987654Test.txt".  It would find both "123456" and "987654" and report those back to you.

If you want to find filenames that have exactly one occurrence of an exact six digit sequence then you could modify the above to:

```
        Dim RegexPattern As String = "(?<![0-9])[0-9]{6}(?![0-9])" ' exactly six digits
        For Each FullPathFileName As String In Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath)
            Dim FileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FullPathFileName) ' exclude the path portion, just search the filename itself
            Dim matches As RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(FileName, RegexPattern)
            If matches.Count = 1 Then
                Debug.Print(matches(0).Value & " in " & FullPathFileName)
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: I was figuring it would have to do with regex. I will attempt to modify my code for results and return for further assistqance or kudos. Thanks for a jumping point.

Comment: Function works great. Thanks for your help. Needed to call it as a separate function but it worked so kudos.